# Change button depending on if photo is liked in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am adding a functionality in my website, where users can like posts.

I have successfully done this, however I am having trouble adding one functionality.

This is text within a button depending on whether a post is liked or not.

Right now the button stays the same no matter if the post is liked or not.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Like', related_name='likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary_pretty(self):
        return self.summary[:50]

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

class Like(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def likepost(request, post_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
        user = request.user
        if post.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            like = Like()
            like.post = post
            like.user = user
            like.status = True
            like.save()
            post.likes.add(user)
            return redirect('home')
```

my template:

```
  {% if post.likes.status == True %}
        <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Unlike {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Like {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
    {% endif %}
```

EDIT - HOME VIEW:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts/home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

EDIT 2:

```
 {% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    {% for post in posts.all %}
      <div class="container pl-5">
        <div class="row pt-3">
            <img src="{% static 'grey.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="60px">
            <div class="pt-3 pl-5" style="position: absolute;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="card" style="width: 600px; bottom: 24px; right: 15px;">
            <img src="{{ post.file.url }}" width="599px">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="card" style="width: 600px; bottom: 50px; right: 15px;">  <img src="{% static 'grey.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="150px">    </div>
        <div class="col-6" style="bottom:145px; left: 5px;">
            <div style="position: absolute;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary_pretty }}</div>
        </div>
        {% for like in post.likes.all %}
          {{like.username}}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if like.status %}
                 <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Unlike {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
        {% else %}
                 <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('likepost{{ post.id }}').submit()}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><span class="oi oi-caret-top"></span> Like {{ post.total_likes }} </button></a>
        {% endif %}
        <form id="likepost{{ post.id }}" method="POST" action="{% url 'likepost' post.id %}">
          {% csrf_token%}
          <input type="hidden">
        </form>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Which version of django are you using? Asking because of the function-based view...

Comment: You need `post.save()` call before redirects.

Comment: I am using the latest version of django.

Comment: Also, I have added post.save( ) before the redirects, and still the same issue occurs.

Comment: Are you doing a page refresh in your Javascript `.submit()` function? Unless you do a page refresh, you template will stay the same and your like button will not change

Comment: I am just calling my url to like my post in .submit() not refreshing. However I do a redirect to 'home' when the button is pressed as you can see in my views.py, which refreshes the page.

Comment: Is the home page where you have the like button?

Comment: Yes my like button is on the home page.

Comment: Please include the view that actually renders the code that you included under `my template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you have defined `likes` as a `ManyToManyField` field:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Like', related_name='likes')
```

But in your template you are trying to get a single boolean value from many likes:

```
{% if post.likes.status == True %}
```

`post.likes` will return multiple objects. You need to instead get the like based on the user.

**EDIT:**
One way you could get the like status is by doing the following in your view:

```
context['like'] = Like.objects.get(post=post, user=request.user)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if like.status == True %}
```

Comment: Oh so post.likes returns multiple objects. How would I get the like based on the user. How can I implement this in my website?

Comment: @djangoninja see the suggestion in the edit and give that a try

Comment: Is this relating to the home view?

Comment: Where would I put this code in? When I put it into my home view, It returns an error saying 'Post is not defined'

Comment: Check the original post where I have added my home view cod .(Which renders home page)

Comment: Also, when I put this in my likecode view, It returns 'Context is not defined'.

Comment: You put it in your view that renders your post page which contains your like button. You have not included this in your post, so it's difficult for me to help you with specifics.

Comment: The edit bit of my original post is where the rendering happens for my post page. The home page renders all the posts and is where the like button is.

Comment: Look at the original post where I have added the post page, where the posts are rendered and the like button is.

Comment: Oh Ok. What method would you recommend to encounter this issue?

Comment: Would you recommend using a .annotate method in my home view for each post. This is what some other people recommended doing.

Comment: @djangoninja Exactly

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of .annotate is. The Django documentation doesn't make sense to me, and I don't understand where in my code, how or why I should perform this .annotate method.

Comment: My friend, I am very hesitant to assist further. There are numerous websites (besides the docs) that explain annotations and give good examples. With some effort, I'm sure you will be able figure it out. I am reluctant to assist if you haven't put in much effort to try and figure it out yourself. You need to at least show what you have tried. That's how you receive help on StackOverflow. Besides, if I post the solution here for you, you will not learn very much. Understanding annotations is beyond the scope of this your original question now.

Comment: Ok thanks Daniel I will look into it. Are you sure for definite that annotations is what I need for this issue to be resolved, and then if so I can look into it.

Comment: Yes. Please update your question so that if anyone else comes across this question, they may feel inclined to answer it, or just mark my answer as accepted